# How can I get the value of checked (checkbox) and autocomplete a textInput in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, checkbox

could you help me?, I'm developing with react native and typescript, I need to do this:
I have a checkBox that tells the user to check if his name is the same as his credit card, if he clicks the checkbox, a TextInput with his name is autocompleted,
if you don't click the checkbox that he can type his name.
I have a variable like: user_name
I don't have code because I don't know how to do it, but I think it goes something like this:

```
 const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
...
return(
            <CheckBox
              checked={setChecked}
              onPress={}
              checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
              uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
              checkedColor='blue'
              uncheckedColor='blue'
            />


        <TextInput
          placeholder='Nombre completo'
          value={}
          onChangeText={}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could implement this as follows under the assumption that the name of the credit card is available. Let us call it `creditCardName`.

My example uses [react-native-checkbox](https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox) and the standard `TextInput` component. If you are using a different component, then the overall pattern still stays the same.

```js
const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(false);
const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');

return (
    <CheckBox
        value={isChecked}
        onPress={(newVal) => setChecked(newVal)}
     />
     <TextInput
       editable={!isChecked}
       placeholder='Nombre completo'
       value={isChecked ? creditCardName : userName}
       onChangeText={setUserName}
     />
)
```

The key-parts are as follows:

1. Let the `TextInput` be editable if and only if `isChecked` is false, that is the `CheckBox` is unchecked.
2. Let `value` of the `TextInput` be the `creditCardName` if the `CheckBox` is checked and set it to the `userName` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't understand what newVal means or where that variable comes from? could you explain me please

Comment: The `onPress` prop of the `CheckBox` component receives a function that gets a boolean value as an input. This boolean value indicates whether or not the `CheckBox` is checked. This is done by the component. We can name it `newVal` or whatever name we prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work (run the snippet for demonstration)

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('checkBox')
var input = document.createElement('input')
var submit = document.querySelector("#submit")
var name = "Tom"

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(input)
    input.value = name
  } else {
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    input.value = ""
  }
})

submit.onclick = function() {
  console.log(input.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```